# Python - random module - generate random numbers from 2 options

Tags: python

This is a python file:

```
import random

class Man:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_men = []
        self.createBody()

    def createBody:
        xCoord = -1
                while xCoord < 16:
                    yCoord = 0
                    xCoord += 1
                    while yCoord < 17:
                        self.list_of_men.append(Body(xCoord, yCoord, val, self))
class Body:
def __init__(self, menX, menY, value, man_obj):
    self.man_obj = man_obj
    self.menX = xCoord
    self.menY = yCoord
    self.value = val
```

Actually, I am appending xCoord and yCoord to a list and also want to append a value to it which is either 0 or 3. The loop goes through 289 times and out of that 289 times, there has to be a randomly generated number which is 0 or 3 that is also appended to the list (3 can be appended only 35 times).

*Note: the self appended is actually man_obj in next class so that we can use the functions of the first class by the second class.

Comment: Is this a percentage chance for 0 vs 3, or your function will be called exactly 289 times and must return exactly 35 3's?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Since we're dealing with small quantities, we could initialize a list of 289 elements of 0, and randomly disperse some 3's inside. Then you can just pop off that list. This solution wouldn't scale well, but it might meet your specific need.

```
import random

def foo():
    a = [0] * 289

    i = 0
    while i < 35:
        index = random.randint(0, 288)
        if a[index] == 0:
            a[index] = 3
            i += 1

    while a:
        yield a.pop()
```

Is this a homework assignment or something similar? Is there a more specific larger problem you're trying to solve? Seems like an unusual requirement.

Comment: Maybe if you post what you have so far it will be easier to understand what you're trying to do and what you are having trouble with.

Comment: 289 is the number of times an append is made. So with those appends, I want another variable after xCoord and yCoord which is value and has to be an integer of either 0 or 3. 35 is a limit that the number of times 3 can be appended can be no more than 35. the rest would be 0's. BUT ALL should be random. so for e.g: (xCoord, yCoord, val) = (2,3, 0) is for the 1st time we run the code.... The second time. it could be (2,3, 3)... HAS TO BE RANDOM

Comment: So it can be up to 35 times but could be less than 35?

Comment: As far as I can tell, what I posted meets your criteria. You could drop that code in and call foo() in your value assignment and as long as it's called exactly 289 times you will have an evenly random distribution of 35 3's.

Answer (score 0):

> I am appending xCoord and yCoord to a list and also want to append a value to it which is either 0 or 3. The loop goes through 289 times and out of that 289 times, there has to be a randomly generated number which is 0 or 3 that is also appended to the list (3 can be appended only 35 times).

So how can there be 289 iterations if you can only allow 3 to be appended 35 times?

Are you talking about something like this?

```
from random import choice

d = list()
for x in range(289):
    if d.count(3) >= 35:
        d.append(0)
    else:
        d.append(choice([0, 3]))
```

Comment: This would have a pretty heavy bias towards the beginning of the list, and could also result in less than 35 instances of 3 which may not be a desired behavior.